# Visual Basic - Using Relational datatables to create an XML File

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I am using VisualBasic in VisualStudio 2017

The goal of my program is to use a datagridview to generate an xml file.

The XML I want to be able to create should look like this:

```
 <dsetDataManager xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsetDataManager.xsd">
  <NetworkAnalyzerTrace>
   <TraceName>S21ZoomedIn</TraceName> 
   <Channel>Channel1</Channel> 
   <Measurement>S21</Measurement> 
   <Format>LogMag</Format> 
   <MinFrequencyStartParam>1.5</MinFrequencyStartParam> 
   <MinFrequencyStartEnum>AutoSpanByBandwidthOrQ</MinFrequencyStartEnum> 
   <MinFrequencyStopParam /> 
   <MinFrequencyStopEnum /> 
   <FrequencyStartParam>4</FrequencyStartParam> 
   <FrequencyStartEnum>AutoSpanByBandwidthOrQ</FrequencyStartEnum> 
   <FrequencyStopParam /> 
   <FrequencyStopEnum /> 
   <NumPoints>101</NumPoints> 
   <SpecEquation>
    <Name>FrequencyDelta</Name> 
    <Filter>1</Filter> 
    <Band>1</Band> 
    <MinEquation>-(0.005 + TuneIndex * (0.003/250))</MinEquation> 
    <MaxEquation>0.005 + TuneIndex * (0.003/250)</MaxEquation> 
    <MinInclusion>Inclusive</MinInclusion> 
    <MaxInclusion>Inclusive</MaxInclusion>
   </SpecEquation>
  </NetworkAnalyzerTrace>
 </dsetDataManager>
```

My Dataset is 'dsetDataManager'. My dataTables are 'NetworkAnalyzerTrace' and 'SpecEquation'. The way I am creating this xml file is by using :

```
dsetDataManager.writeXML('FilePath')
```

I use the DataGridView to create the rows for each table. How do I write the XML file with the 'SpecEquation' DataTable nested inside of the 'NetworkAnalyzerTrace'?

I currently have no issue creating the XML with the 'SpecEquation' outside of 'NetworkAnalyzerTrace', The issue is just inserting it into that other datatable.

Thank you very much

***UPDATE***
Thank you everyone for your comments they were very instructive. I did some more research and found that the main question I had was about relational columns in DataTables. I figured out how to establish these relationships between tables and the writeXML function nests the tables within the parent table.

Comment: Convert your dataset into a class structure which can be serialized directly into your xml format. The class to be serialized can be generated in the IDE automatically by copying the xml you have above and doing Edit >> Paste Special >> Paste XML as classes. Then extend the generated class by adding methods to take the datatables and convert them into the class structure. Finally, serialize.

Comment: Also, I think you have the makings of a decent question, but there is already a closure vote for this question being too broad. As it stands, it might be... but I suggest you add some more code to clear up any questions about the datatables and their relationships with the dgv.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new at this. I am not really sure how to narrow the questionsdown more than: Writing a dataset to xml and nest data tables in the xml

Answer (score 0):

As @djv suggested, create a class of your XML structure. Place each row in a list and serialize the list. This will do it:

Class 1

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property c2 As Class2

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub


    Public Sub New(i As Integer, s As String)
        Me.Id = i
        Me.Name = s
        Me.c2 = New Class2(i + 1000, "CLASS 2 " & s)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Class 2

```
Public Class Class2
    Public Property MyId As Integer
    Public Property MyName As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(i As Integer, s As String)
        Me.MyId = i
        Me.MyName = s
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code to serialize. Place a button in your form

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim list As New List(Of Class1)
        For index As Integer = 1 To 2
            list.Add(New Class1(index, "OBJECT " & index.ToString))
        Next

        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Class1)))
        Using stream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("T:\SER.TXT")
            serializer.Serialize(stream, list)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfClass1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Class1>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>OBJECT 1</Name>
    <c2>
      <MyId>1001</MyId>
      <MyName>CLASS 2 OBJECT 1</MyName>
    </c2>
</Class1>
<Class1>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>OBJECT 2</Name>
    <c2>
      <MyId>1002</MyId>
      <MyName>CLASS 2 OBJECT 2</MyName>
    </c2>
</Class1>
</ArrayOfClass1>
```